# Any criteria to choose between Laplace and Fourier transform to solve a PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm taking a PDE class and we recently started working on integral transform methods. Besides this question, I was also wondering why wouldn't you always choose the Laplace transform over the Fourier transform.

Comment: Inverting a Fourier transform is usually easier

Comment: Depends on the domain on the variable. If the variable you are transforming is defined on $(0,\infty)$ (e.g time) then you take the Laplace transform. If it’s defined over all of $\mathbb R$ then you take the Fourier transform.